# Using my own hierarchy in network analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst

I am trying to use a hierarchy in my network model, but I have already assigned a hierarchy in my attribute table through a new field. All the ArcGis help guides point towards using the standard hierarchy ranges given:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=types_of_evaluators_used_by_a_network&anchor=hierarchies

How do I go about using my own hierarchy ranges?

Comment: First thing I'd check is the correct documentation [About network analysis with hierarchy](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/network-analysis-with-hierarchy.htm) as the link you've posted is for version 9.3 and you've tagged 10.3.

Comment: How have you defined your hierarchy ranges?  Can you give an example?